# Pandas: create column in multi-indexed dataframe from the relative indexes of elements within their group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following multi-indexed dataframe:

```
                      count
site_url   visit_id

a.com      1          100
           11         102
           21         99

b.com      2          231
           12         229
           22         229
```

Where all the first level index groups have the same size, that is for each `site_url` I have an equal number `N` of elements (I only included 3 in my example but there are actually more).

I would like to turn this data frame into:

```
              a.com   b.com
visit_index

1             100     231
2             102     229
3             99      229
.
.
.
N             ...     ...
```

So that I can plot each column as a line with `N` data points.

The issue I'm running into is, **how do I convert each `visit_id` value (all unique) into a "visit index relative to its website"?** That is, visit ids 1, 11, 21, ... for website a.com would map to visit indexes 1, 2, 3, ... N, and so would visit ids for b.com, c.com, etc.

Once this is done, I believe I can use values of `site_url` as columns with `df.unstack()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['visit_index'] = df.groupby(level='site_url').cumcount()
df = df.reset_index().set_index('visit_index')
print(df.pivot(columns='site_url', values='count'))
```

Prints:

```
site_url     a.com  b.com
visit_index              
0              100    231
1              102    229
2               99    229
```

Comment: It worked, thank you. I didn't know about the .cumcount() method, very handy.